# Detect when a window is being closed and pass the path of the window in C#

Tags: c#, windows, explorer

I'm trying to develop the software I described in this post:

[Get the path of every explorer window with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520879/get-the-path-of-every-explorer-window-with-c-sharp)

After I better analyzed the problem I found that I need to build a list with the "closed windows" not with the "current open windows".

I want to know if there is a way to catch the close window action and pass the path of that window to a variable in C#.

I appreciate the response had a little explanation and not just the code, to really understand what the code does.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [CBT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_cbthook) hook to receive notification of windows being closed. Note that this would likely be easier from native code. From mananged code you will expend a lot of energy working out p/invoke signatures, marshalling etc.

Comment: Subscribe to the DShellWindowsEvents.WindowRevoked event.

Comment: @RaymondChen And how can I do that? Is difficult to find clear information.

Comment: @Memochipan Um, [a search for DShellWindowsEvents](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DShellWindowsEvents) quickly turns up [this program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239323/internetexplorer-automation-object-performancecounter-not-working). You just need to subscribe to the WindowRevoked event instead of WindowCreated.